# Android how to make new Contacts in contacts app opens Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts

I'm making an app that sync its contacts with the phone's contact list app.

**this is What i have:**

- my app has a sync adapter.
- I mannage to sync the contacts.
- The contacts are there.
- At the end I get something like this:

[SCREENSHOT](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12854948/screenshot_2013-08-07_1056.png)

This is cool.

**My problem:**

I need to open my app when the user clicks on the "my APP" row. 
But I have no idea how to do this.
I have like 3 days browsing on google and found nothing...

**This might help:**

When i click on the facebook row i get something like this:

```
I/ActivityManager( 2014): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/10940 cmp=com.facebook.katana/.ContactUriHandler } from pid 18506
```

Email row:

```
I/ActivityManager( 2014): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.SENDTO dat=mailto:yb_test_001%40hotmail.com cmp=com.google.android.gm/.ComposeActivityGmail } from pid 18346
```

"My app" row:

```
I/ActivityManager( 2014): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/11653 } from pid 18506
E/Infinite(18506): ContactInfoListAdapter: No activity found for external item. android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.contacts/data/11653 }
```

I can see that in "my app" case the cmp=[package_name]/.[some_activity] part is missing... **where can i set this?**

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hey Have you Entered it into the android manifest?

Should look something like this:

```
<activity android:name="Activity Name"></activity>
```

Comment: I have, all my activities are in there...
But I cant find how to specify that I want that the clicks on contacts that I have created open that activity. For example, my "main"

Comment: Solved, my problem was indeed with the <activity> the intent filter was missing. I put something like this <intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/><category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/><data android:mimeType="MYCONTACTMIMETYPE"/></intent-filter> and now it works! 

Thanks for the help!